# Send notifications to nearby Mobile Devices through Bluetooth Low Energy(i.e. via beacons) with no app installed on their device

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, wifi

I am trying to send notification to mobile devices without any application installed in **their** phone. Their devices may or may not be connected to the BLE device. Is there a way to make this happen?

I have tried to do the same thing with WiFi. No luck there. Any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that will ever be possible since Google would never allow automatic notifications broadcasted by untrusted devices without user consent.

Comment: To add to that, the closest thing that *allowed* you to do that were BLE beacons (https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/overview). However, even this was disabled due to spammy and irrelevant content. More information can be found here (https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/discontinuing-support-for-android.html).